# I am creating a android project which will save username and password of the user, I am getting error while running the app on device

Tags: java, android

```
06-12 18:20:51.794 17318-17379/zaphlabs.com.knotty E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: zaphlabs.com.knotty, PID: 17318
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: username (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, username, password FROM knot
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1163)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1034)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1202)
        at zaphlabs.com.knotty.database.KnotProvider.query(KnotProvider.java:55)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1027)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:238)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:502)
        at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:64)
        at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:42)
        at `enter code here`android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:312)
        at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
        at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:57)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

Please help me in this. I am getting error from a very long time and not able to solve this below is my full code which you may see to help me out.

[Code is Here](https://github.com/iammohdzaki/Knotty)

Comment: may be your table is not created or you are access wrong column that's why you are getting this error.

Comment: you need to read the error before you post it. the error tells you what is wrong. Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: username (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, username, password FROM knot

Comment: Look at your `CREATE TABLE` statement in `KnotDBHelper.java` - you're missing a ton of spaces, it's an invalid statement. Please also post your database classes *as text, as part of the question*, not as a GitHub link

Comment: `SQLiteException: no such column: username` means that your table has `no such column: username`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the stcak trace the column 'username' not exists in table 'knots'. I hope the create table statement is failed because of syntax failure (spaces missing).

Try below create statement, (make sure you uninstall and install app again to check, becauase create table query not called on update)

```
      String CREATE_KNOT_PET_TABLE_ENTRIES="CREATE TABLE "+ KnotContract.KnotEntry.TABLE_NAME+ " ("+
           _ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
           COLUMN_USERNAME+" TEXT NOT NULL,"+
           COLUMN_PASSWORD+" TEXT );";
```

Comment: Thanks bro finally solved